# Unable to click the Stripe checkout button with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, testing, stripe-payments, puppeteer

I am testing my Stripe checkout process with Puppeteer.
I managed to fill out the form, however I cannot get Puppeteer to click the "Start trial" button, this one:

[image: Start trial button]

the html of the button is as follows:

```
<button class="SubmitButton SubmitButton--complete" type="submit" data-testid="hosted-payment-submit-button" style="background-color: rgb(0, 116, 212); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div class="SubmitButton-Shimmer SubmitButton--complete-Shimmer" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 116, 212, 0) 0%, rgb(58, 139, 238) 50%, rgba(0, 116, 212, 0) 100%);"></div><div class="SubmitButton-TextContainer"><span class="SubmitButton-Text SubmitButton-Text--current Text Text-color--default Text-fontWeight--500 Text--truncate" aria-hidden="false">Start trial</span><span class="SubmitButton-Text SubmitButton-Text--pre Text Text-color--default Text-fontWeight--500 Text--truncate" aria-hidden="true">Processing...</span></div><div class="SubmitButton-IconContainer"><div class="SubmitButton-Icon SubmitButton-Icon--current"><div class="Icon Icon--md Icon--square"><svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false"><path d="M3 7V5a5 5 0 1 1 10 0v2h.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v6a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-9a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a1 1 0 0 1 1-1zm5 2.5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v2a1 1 0 0 0 2 0v-2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1zM11 7V5a3 3 0 1 0-6 0v2z" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></div></div><div class="SubmitButton-Icon SubmitButton-SpinnerIcon SubmitButton-Icon--pre"><div class="Icon Icon--md Icon--square"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false"><ellipse cx="12" cy="12" rx="10" ry="10" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ellipse></svg></div></div></div><div class="SubmitButton-CheckmarkIcon"><div class="Icon Icon--md"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="14" focusable="false"><path d="M 0.5 6 L 8 13.5 L 21.5 0" fill="transparent" stroke-width="2" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></div></div></button>
```

and I am trying to click the button with this:

```
await page.click(".SubmitButton");
```

However, it throws an error saying:

> Node is either not clickable or not an HTMLElement

I tried clicking it using selectors of multiple children of the button and had no success.
I went to the console of the browser and typed in:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("SubmitButton");
btns[0].click()
```

and it just works (the button is clicked and it redirects to the success page), so the selector must be right.
I also tried adding different timeouts, but it didn't work either.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: I am not sure how to do this with Puppeteer but with Stripe there are often easier ways to do automated testing than something that automatically clicks through the page. Can you tell me a bit more about what you are trying to test here?

Comment: I am just doing end-to-end testing for my app, so clicking through the page is kind of mandatory here. One of the parts that I am testing is the checkout process, i.e. from the moment a user clicks 'subscribe' in my app to the success page upon the successful checkout process in Stripe. I have separate unit and integration tests for each individual part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I hit this issue it's usually because of one of these 3 errors:

- element is not present/visible when I click it;
- element is not ready when I click it (maybe some background logic taking a bit a time in the tested website or something);
- it's one of these times where Puppeteer just plays with you;

To get rid of the 2 first reason, make sure you wait for your element to be present, and add some delay before your click (set a high delay for debugging, then you can reduce it as it fits you):

```js
// wait for element
const myElement = await page.waitForSelector(".SubmitButton", {visible: true});
// add some delay
await page.waitForTimeout(5000); // 5s
// click your elem
await myElement.click();
```

If it still doesn't work, then you hit the 3rd issue, the only workaround I've found for the moment is to click the element using `page.evaluate`:

```js
const locator = ".SubmitButton";
await page.evaluate( (paramLocator) => {
    document.querySelector(paramLocator).click();
}, locator);
```